DEM < 10 Meters - Greece
I would like to know if there is any free or to buy option (site) from which I can buy/download a high resolution DEM for a small region in Greece.  Except from USGS and OpenToography where the products are >30m  do I have any other option?
Sorry for not having any practical info to attach.

Maybe Open DEM? https://www.opendem.info/

@Babel thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, for Greece there is no high resolution as i want from this provider [Opendem].

If you use QGIS, there is a pre-installed worldwide DEM under XYZ-tiles, called Mapzen global terrain. For Greece, there seems to be a resolution of ca. 4 m.
You can load it in QGIS as raster layer for symbology or you can download the extent for your region of interest locally for processing etc.: RIght click layer -> Export -> Save As...
XYZ-tile raster layer Mapzen Global Terrain rendered in 5m contour lines for the Acropolis and surroundings in Athens:

Same area, same data in 3D view, vertical scale 1.5:

Mount Athos in 3D view (vertical scale of 1):

Same, with OpenTopoMap as background:


thank you again for your very interesting comment! But i have the following question. To use it should i have the contrours of my area or i can calculate DEM for my area without having contours for her?

You don't need any contours. You can download the DEM and if you need, you create the contours from the DEM.

something  is wrong and i get errors. However thank you for the help. I will try it more :)
